# Authenticating a controller method for both web access and web service

Tags: laravel, web-services, api, authentication, jwt

I have written a method (`listItems`) in myController class which return all records of a table in JSON format.
I added a middleware in __consturct method to authenticate all accesses to methods of this controller from the web access.

```php
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('auth');
}

public function listItems(Request $request)
{
    $currentUser = JWTAuth::parseToken()->authenticate();
    $items = ItemList::where('user_id', $currentUser->id)->get();
    return  $items;
}
```

I also have a web service for mobile application that needs to have access to `listItem` method. I used `JWT` for authenticating mobile access to my web service.
The problem is that when the mobile application posts an authentication token which is necessary to access to the `listItem` via API, It shows me login page for web access. 
In other words, it looks, I can't handle both authentications for one method of a controller.

Comment: i think you should use the `api` middleware group for API requests?

Comment: web middleware are different from api middleware. you can check file `app\Http\Krenel.php`, if you are using `JWT` better to have different routes in `web` and `api` and have `Auth` guard in web routes and `Auth:api` guard in api routes